# .Net MVC Object Parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm creating a web page to manage my settings on a website. The settings are stored as a JSON file, and then parsed as runtime in to a 'CoreSettings' object.

My current code is as such:

```
public ActionResult Settings(WebDocInterop.Settings.CoreSettings id)
{
   if(id != null)
   {
     // Set the settings here
   }
}
```

I then have a form page which displays the fields within CoreSettings:

```
<form method="post">
  <input name="SomeSettingName" id="SomeSettingName">
  <button>Save</button>
</form>
```

When pressing the submit, my initial expectation was that the CoreSetting object would be populated by the settings that are named in the form, however, upon inspection it looks as though the object is being initialized, but the fields are always null.

Would anybody be able to confirm to me if this is the correct way to approach the situation, or if I'm going to have to use the 'FormCollection' parameter?

Comment: Please show the structure of the `CoreSettings` model.

Answer (score 0):

This has been resolved by using the writing a method to convert a FormCollection to required object.